protect data in transit while using azure vault encryption methods
We have used azure key vault wrap, unwrap & encrypt & decrypt method using .net core 6 CryptographyClient object to perform the operation.
To connect the azure key vault we are using the https connection and a certificate that is installed on server key store where my application is deployed.
The question came; how the in transit data is protected? the plane text data for encryption that we are sending over the public network to azure for cypto operation?
As per my understanding the certificate & and secured (https) call we are making is guarding the in transit data.
But the audit party is not convinced and I also not getting any right reference where it clearly mentioned about how the data is protected while using  wrap, unwrap & encrypt & decrypt methods.
ChatGpt search https://chatgpt.com/share/1865af15-04a5-411d-a0a8-221647b31ea9 provided the content under heading "Secure Channels" saying data is protected while using these functions but what is the source that statement I am interested, or any authentic source if someone can help me with.

@DasariKamali, we are using both the options of key vault, encrypt/decrypt, wrap/unwrap. encrypt/decrypt are used for payload data encryption & wrap & unwrap are used for password like values to wrap unwrap.

no, I am able to use the encrypt/decrypt and wrap/unwrap my question is when we are passing the data to these methods how data is protected when it transmitted over the internet.

Not sure where you got on this. Are you referring to the transit of the keys or the data your'e encrypting/decrypting? You get the key by using managed identity or client credentials (like a REST API call), this is protected using a https request. Enrypting files should be done locally using public keys, decrypting files can either be done through Azure decryption endpoint or a local decryption agent - this uses a KID to get the private key to decrypt
